# Trying to Post from Browser, Method not allowed

Tags: angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc

im trying add new data to my database, i'm using wcf.

This is my iServiceRequest.cs

```js
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
              RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
              ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
              UriTemplate = "/InsertData?ticket={ticket}&request={request}&category={category}&subCategory={subCategory}&subject={subject}&body={body}&assignto={assignto}&status={status}&fileName={fileName}&fileContent={fileContent}&fileBinary={fileBinary}&IsActive={IsActive}&createdBy={createdBy}&ACNo={ACNo}")]
        IEnumerable<USP_INSERT_DATA_Result> InsertData(string ticket, string request, string category, string subCategory, string subject, string body, string assignto, int status, string fileName, string fileContent, byte[] fileBinary, bool IsActive, string createdBy, int ACNo);
```

When i try to post from browser using

```js
http://localhost:51458/ServiceRequest.svc/InsertData?ticket=ticket&request=request&category=categor&subCategory=subCategory&subject=subject&body=body&assignto=assignto&status=1&fileName=fileName&fileContent=fileContent&fileBinary=13213&IsActive=1&createdBy=createdBy&ACNo=111
```

i'm getting service method is not allowed, you can see it on image below

[Image Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLjt3.png)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers will always make get request.
use postman or telerik fiddler to do post.

If you pass all the values in query string then you can use simple GET.

Comment: But i have new error, can i ask in here?

this is my error `The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.'.`

do you have any clue what to do?

Comment: @Randy, sounds like you're posting bad data. I would recommend you post a new question, and give the data you are posting as it's a different problem to the one raised in this question.

Comment: Thanks. Kindly post a new question with your service method

Comment: thanks for your advice, ok next i'll create new one @Adrian

Comment: yes its a good idea, it will make everybody can identify my problem @KalyanaSundaram